# Why I need to use SELF in Python?

Tags: python

The following code is working

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name1, roll1):
        self.name = name1
        self.roll = roll1

ram = Student("Ram", 1)

print(ram.name)
print(ram.roll)
```

But, it's not working without the `self` while declaring the variables as follows.

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name1, roll1):
        name = name1
        roll = roll1

ram = Student("Ram", 1)

print(ram.name)
print(ram.roll)
```

I am new to Python, and just wanted to understand the internal logic of this `self`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: do you want to understand the design rationale behind always requiring self? Unlike java-'this' which is usually optional?

Comment: Without self, it's just a local variable. With self, it becomes a member.

Comment: without `self`, you are making some local variables that are "forgotten" as soon as the `__init__` method is completed. By setting them to `self` object they are bound to the instance of `Student` and can be accessed from anywhere else.

Comment: Without the `self` the variables are local to the function (in this case, method).  With the `self`, they refer to attributes of the class instance.  Remember, methods are just functions that happen to be bound to class attributes.  That has no effect on how it resolves variable references.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-self-parameter-why-is-it-needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, the self keyword is used in object-oriented programming to refer to the instance of the class itself. It's not a reserved keyword in Python but a strong convention. Understanding its role is key to grasp how Python handles object-oriented concepts.

Here's why self is important:

-Instance Attribute Assignment: When you create an instance of a class, self is used to refer to that specific instance. This allows for each instance of a class to have its own set of attributes. In your working example, self.name and self.roll are instance attributes, meaning each Student object will have its own name and roll. Without self, name and roll would be treated as local variables in the **init** method, and they wouldn't be accessible outside of this method.

-Method Calls on the Object: self is also used to call other methods from within the class. This is important for accessing or modifying the object's state.

-Clarity and Readability: Using self makes it clear that the variable is associated with the instance of the class, not a local or a global variable. This distinction improves code readability.

In your non-working example, name and roll are local to the **init** method. Once this method finishes execution, these local variables are discarded, and there's no way to access them from the instance of the class. That's why ram.name and ram.roll raise an error, as these attributes don't exist on the ram instance.

Comment: `self` is not a keyword.  It's a variable name, like any other.  It can be anything you want.  You could change it to `me` if you wanted. Keywords are recognized by the parser.  Examples:  `def`, `if`, `for`, etc.  Not `self`.  There's no such thing as a non-reserved keyword.  It's either a reserved keyword, or it's not a keyword.

Comment: neat, didn't know that

Comment: Could you tell us where you found this text you posted as an answer?

Comment: Thank you @SuperStew for the detailed explanation.

Comment: @TomKarzes not entirely true: now `match` and `case` are sorta non-reserved (called "soft keywords" in PEP and `keyword` module), and `async/await` used to be similar soft keywords (implemented with a hack) in 3.5-3.6. Those are not reserved in sense of usage: you can have a variable called `match`, it becomes a keyword only in context of match-case statement.

Comment: @STerliakov Interesting.  It doesn't apply to `self`, which is never a keyword, but I didn't realize there are some identifiers that are keywords only in certain contexts.